# Execute automake from eclipse autotools plugin

Tags: c, eclipse, autotools

I recently installed the autotools plugin for eclipse. I made the Makefile.am for each source subdirectory. I also included the AM_INIT_MAKEFILE macro in the configure.ac file. The plugin **DOES** use `autoreconf -i`. The problem is that I get an error anytime I try to build that says,
`config.status: error: cannot find input file: 'Makefile.in'`
Which indicates that automake was never ran. Any ideas?

Comment: The typical command line tool used to regenerate the Autotools-managed files is invoked as `autoreconf -i`. Maybe you can find something related to that in the GUI? (I'm not familiar with the plugin.)

Comment: The plugin DOES use autoreconf -i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a beginner's mistake. I didn't add the extra files automake needs to actually function and make the Makefile.in. Also to run any autotool (aclocal, automake, autoheader, etc.) go to Project->Invoke Autotools->Invoke (name of autotool)